# Error while merging XML files

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Here is the code am trying to merge merge multiple XML files.

```
public static void mergeXml(String directory) throws Exception {
    File dir = new File(directory);
    File[] rootFiles = dir.listFiles();
    XMLEventWriter eventWriter;
    XMLEventFactory eventFactory;
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    eventWriter = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream("temp/testMerge1.xml"));
    eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();

    // Create and write Start Tag
    StartDocument startDocument = eventFactory.createStartDocument("ISO-8859-1");
    eventWriter.add(startDocument);

    for(File rootFile : rootFiles){
        XMLEventReader test = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new StreamSource(rootFile));
        while(test.hasNext()){
            XMLEvent event= test.nextEvent();
            //avoiding start(<?xml version="1.0"?>) and end of the documents;
            if (event.getEventType()!= XMLEvent.START_DOCUMENT && event.getEventType() != XMLEvent.END_DOCUMENT)
                eventWriter.add(event);         

            test.close();
        }           

        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndDocument());
        eventWriter.close();
    }

}
```

am getting two problems

1. the output file is not having any encoding
2. when am trying to parse the file created by this code am getting the following exception

```
[Fatal Error] :1:2493: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at SplitMain.validateInputFile(SplitMain.java:139)
    at SplitMain.main(SplitMain.java:76)
```

Comment: The malformed xml error might also come up if file encoding is detected incorrect. Especially if it contains non-latin characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create and write Start Tag
StartDocument startDocument = eventFactory.createStartDocument("ISO-8859-1");
eventWriter.add(startDocument);
```

This does not create a root element for the output XML document, it simply writes the `<?xml` declaration.  After the `StartDocument` you also need to add a suitable `StartElement`:

```
StartElement startRootElt = eventFactory.createStartElement("", "http://example.com", "root");
eventWriter.add(startRootElt);
```

The next problem is that you're closing the `eventWriter` inside the for loop:

```
    eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndDocument());
    eventWriter.close();
}
```

You need to move this outside the `for` loop, and also end the root element we started above

```
}
eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndElement("", "http://example.com", "root"));
eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndDocument());
eventWriter.close();
```

Additionally, if any of your XML files has a `<!DOCTYPE` you may run into problems.  You may just be able to ignore DTD events in the same way you're currently ignoring start and end document events, but whether or not this works depends on exactly what is declared in that DTD.  You'll have to try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that you're trying to blindly add XML nodes into the destination document, and thus, ending up with more than one root element. That is not allowed in XML.

You can make a new top level element in the output document, and append XML nodes to that instead.